# How to enclose a text in box in itextpdf (while generating pdfs)

Tags: itextpdf

I have to display a normal text and then the next following text should be inclosed in a box. how can i do this in itextpdf. is there an easy way.

Example
Name: MY NAME

In the above MY NAME should be inclosed in a box.

Answer (score 0):

If by "box" you mean a colored background, then you can use the [`setBackground()`](http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/Chunk.html#setBackground%28com.itextpdf.text.BaseColor,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float%29) method:

```
Chunk chunk = new Chunk("MY NAME");
chunk.setBackground(BaseColor.RED);
```

You can add 4 parameters to extend the rectangle to the left, bottom, right and top as the API documentation indicates.

If by "box" you mean a rectangle (without background color), you can use a [generic tag event](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=206). The [MovieYears](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=97) example shows you how to add a film strip or an ellipse to certain chunks. The result is shown [here](http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part1/chapter05/movie_years.pdf). The years are put in a small box that looks like pellicule. The IMDB links are put in a blue ellipse.